# How to wait for an HtmlElement to appear in a WebBrowser in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control in my Windows Form, which navigates to a website. The `WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted` event fires 5 times but there are still some scripts that execute afterwards. I have to wait for a specific element to show up before I can consider the page is completely loaded. I tried this:

```vb
While WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username") Is Nothing
    Application.DoEvents()
End While
```

But it seems like it freezes the script on the page (the page even tells me it is offline). If you want to help, you can give me your answer either in VB or in C#.

**EDIT :** I am now using a method where I use a Timer to check every 100ms if the element has appeared.

Comment: in which event are you running this code, is it during page load?

Comment: @YogeshHShenoy I have a counter and I execute this code in WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, at the fifth time it fires

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that <sub>(pretty much)</sub> any solution that uses `Application.DoEvents()` is a ***bad solution***. `DoEvents()` should not be used to keep the User Interface responsive. If you feel that you need to use it then you are most likely doing something wrong. See: [**Keeping your UI responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/).

Instead, check the [**`WebBrowser.ReadyState` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.readystate(v=vs.110).aspx) inside `DocumentCompleted`. It'll tell you if the web page has been fully loaded or not (this does **NOT** take asynchronous/delayed Javascript code into account however).

```vb
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        'Do stuff.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok so I think the script is delayed, because the element appears just after the `ReadyState` is `Complete` (if I put a MessageBox after the 'Do stuff , it will appear just after I click "Ok"). So for now I will keep the Timer method.

Comment: @paulolol : Yeah, I'm afraid there is no better way in that case since webpages can be changed dynamically. I use timers as well for situations like this, starting them the `DocumentCompleted` event handler and stopping them whenever the element is found. The `Windows.Forms.Timer` is a low priority timer based on window messages and has a minimum resolution of ~50 ms. For situations like this where you are only running it for a few seconds doesn't really affect performance.